# How to click on a button using WebControl

Tags: c#, winforms, awesomium

I'm very new to C# and programming overall. In my first WinForms app I used standart WebBrowser but I encountered a lot of problems that are related to Internet Explorer so I started to look for alternatives and found Awesomium. I move very very slow in understanding how it works and right now I've encountered a sirious problem that doesn't allow me to continue and makes me go back to using standart C# WebBrowser.
Here's the code of button I need to click:

```
<span class="r-button r-button_h36 r-input_w200 r-button_graphite" title="Submit" draggable="false" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Registration', 'Click_next_button']);">Submit`<input class="r-button_invisible" name="button.submit" type="submit" value="" tabindex="1"`></span>
```

I've googled the solution for all night long but no luck. 
Already tried using javascripts:

```
cbrowser.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('button.submit')[0].click();");
```

And a lot of variations of it with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times I have to perform all the 3 actions to get the button clicked:

```
// Make sure the web browser is on focus
webView.Focus();
// Find and click the button
webView.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByName('button.submit')[0].click();");
// Update the web browser
WebCore.Update();
```

And sometimes it takes awhile for awesomium to update its stuff or the update is without switching pages(dynamically) and awesomium doesn't have a good DOM control for that as in the navigating status and stuff would not help.

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer, but it didn't help :(

Comment: @user3367804 once you do the click action, are you taking screenshots of it while waiting? I would take at least 5 or 6 screenshots on a interval of 5~10 seconds each just to make sure there is no reaction on awesomium, it some times take action but unnoticed and you can see it on the screenshot. Also it should be `button` and not `button.submit` or If you use `getElementsByName` you can use `button.submit` instead.

Comment: No I don't take screenshots. I'm pretty sure that action must be taken almost instantly because when you manually click on the button it instantly takes you to the next page without waiting, it doesn't even change url of the page. When I used standart WebBrowser I clicked on the button by finding an element in HtmlElementCollection  by it's inner text and it worked just fine.

Comment: It worked! :) Thank you so much for your time and help! I've spent hours and hours looing for solution :) Sorry for my stupidity and thanks again! :)